# Object subclassing approaches

Tags: objective-c, oop

Suppose I was designing a component representing grips on a UI control for resizing it.

[image: Control]

now obviously each grip is not exactly the same in terms of behavior, for instance the top left grip will have to display a North West South East mouse cursor and dragging it will change the size of the control whereas the top middle grip needs to show a north south mouse cursor and dragging it will only allow you to change the height.

In terms of implementation there are two basic approaches:-

**(1)** a constructor which requires you to pass in information as to what kip of grip you are designing and then have a huge switch statement inside to define the actual behavior of the grip like so :-

```
- initWithGripType(int)gripType
{
    switch(gripType {
        case TOP_MIDDLE_GRIP:
            cursorType = northSouthCursor;
            draggedMovement = upDown;
            break;
        case TOP_LEFT_GRIP:
            cursorType = northWestSouthEastCursor;
            draggedMovement = upDownLeftRight;
            break;
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

**(2)** have a grip base class that defines the common attributes. e.g painting a grip is the same no matter which grip it is. And then sub classes for each grip type liks so :-

```
@interface Grip : NSObject {
    NSCursor _cursorType;
    int _draggedMovement;
}

// force init to be unavilable for base class
- (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("Instantiate subclass instead.")));
- (void)drawGrip;

@end;



@interface GripTopLeft : Grip {
}

- (id)init;

@end;

@interface GripBottomLeft : Grip {
}

- (id)init;

@end;

...
...
...
```

Approach two has the advantage that I don't have to maintain any switch statements and can add new grip types at will, the downside is that if I have many grip types, each one is now a separate source and header file.

Is there a third approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to implement this as a single class without having to use an unwieldly switch statement. Here are two:

- Use convenience methods (i.e., factory methods) to get different gripTypes
- Use an `NSDictionary` instead of a switch statement to set up a grip's properties based on its type

I would lean towards keeping it in one method, because if you want to customize the behavior of `Grip` by subclassing, with your second approach you'd have to write another subclass for each type, or revise your class hierarchy.